# Verify or check encodes bracket of string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

How can I check all bracket in JavaScript staring..

```
verify("---(++++)----") -> 1
verify("") -> 1
verify("before ( middle []) after ") -> 1
verify(") (") -> 0
verify("} {") -> 1 //no, this is not a mistake.
verify("<(   >)") -> 0
verify("(  [  <>  ()  ]  <>  )") -> 1
verify("   (      [)") -> 0
```

I have `verify(str)` this will return 1 or 0.i just want to check this `<>,{},[],()` brackets on string,then any one can do this for me. thanks

Comment: Do you want to check if pairs are there i.e (`<` and `>`) ?

Comment: ya i want like this and also this (<>)[]({<<><>>})

Comment: How is `} {` valid? You said `{}` was one of the things to check.

Comment: I'm shocked you actually got people to do your work for you, without providing any attempt what-so-ever.

Comment: @entropic I considered making a fuss, but the algorithm is reasonably complex, while still doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
function verify(str) {
  len = str.length;
  b = [];
  j = 0;
  f = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (str[i] == "(" || str[i] == "<" || str[i] == "[") {
      b[j] = str[i];
      j++;
    }
    if (str[i] == ")" || str[i] == "]" || str[i] == ">") {
      k = b.length - 1;
      if (str[i] == ")") {
        if (b[k] == "(") {
          b.pop();
          j--;
        } else {
          f = 1;
        }
      } else if (str[i] == "]") {
        if (b[k] == "[") {
          b.pop();
          j--;
        } else {
          f = 1;
        }
      } else if (str[i] == ">") {
        if (b[k] == "<") {
          b.pop();
          j--;
        } else {
          f = 1;
        }
      } else {
        f = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  if (f == 1) return 0;
  else return 1;
}

console.log(verify("---(++++)----"));
console.log(verify(""));
console.log(verify("before ( middle []) after "));
console.log(verify(") ("));
console.log(verify("} {"));
console.log(verify("<(   >)"));
console.log(verify("(  [  <>  ()  ]  <>  )"));
console.log(verify("   (      [)"));
```

Comment: Your code is pretty repetitive. You should use another function to handle the repetitive parts, and a loop.

Answer (score 2):

First, remove all characters that aren't `()`, `[]`, or `<>`. Then you can use a recursive function that removes un-nested balanced pairs. If the string is empty after removing all balanced pairs, then the string is valid. Return `1` if it was valid, and return `0` if it was invalid.

```js
function verify(input) {
  return stripBalancedPairs(stripNonPairs(input)) ? 0 : 1;
}
function stripNonPairs(input) {
  return input.replace(/[^()[\]<>]+/g, '');
}
function stripBalancedPairs(input) {
  var str = input.replace(/\(\)|\[]|<>/g, ''); // remove (), [], or <>
  return str === input ? str : stripBalancedPairs(str);
}

console.log(verify("---(++++)----"));              // -> 1
console.log(verify(""));                           // -> 1
console.log(verify("before ( middle []) after ")); // -> 1
console.log(verify(") ("));                        // -> 0
console.log(verify("} {"));                        // -> 1
console.log(verify("<(   >)"));                    // -> 0
console.log(verify("(  [  <>  ()  ]  <>  )"));     // -> 1
console.log(verify("   (      [)"));               // -> 0
```